# SBJsonParser isn't returning correctly, how do I deal with this data?

Tags: iphone

When I use the SBJsonParser I don't get an NSDictionary I can use. Here is the code I used on the JSON string returned by my request:

```
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSDictionary *stuff = [parser objectWithString:jsonString error:nil];
```

When I print out the dictionary it created I see:
    {
    conferences =     (
                (
            "demo",
            "Demo Database"
        ),
                (
            "dev",
            "Development Database"
        ),
                (
            "TESTING",
            "Testing Database"
        ),
                (
            T2011,
            "T 2011"
        ),
                (
            "C2010",
            "C2010"
        )
    );
    }

and I've tried to access some of the data but I am unable to because it does not recognize any of the key's I use. How would I access the data in this Dictionary? Or is this incorrect?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return type is either a NSDictionary or a NSArray depending on the structure of the JSON. In your case the data is probably interpreted as an array of key value pairs which might be returned to you as a NSArray.

**Edit:**
(As seen in the comments below) the parsing result was returned as a NSDictionary with a NSArray for the key "conferences". The NSArray in turn didn't store key value pairs but other NSArrays with two elements each.

Comment: I've tried an array but I am unable to access the data with objectAtIndex

Comment: Do you get an error if you pass in an NSError**? If not, can you set a breakpoint and inspect the returned data?

Comment: I do not get an error. I am getting what I expect for my Json String but the NSDictionary is not being created correctly. The Json string is: {"conferences":[["demo","Demo Database"],["dev","Development Database"],["TESTING","Testing Database"],["T2011","T 2011"],["C2010","C2010"]]}

Comment: is the result I got expected for this JSON string? If it is, how would I access the data?

Comment: I would set a breakpoint and inspect the NSDictionary or NSArray, whichever is returned, to determine the structure and learn which keys to use. Also, you could print out the returned object (not the JSON string) like NSLog(%@, [parser objectWithString:jsonString error:nil]); That should tell you something about what object is being returned and its structure.

Comment: The stuff I printed out in my original post is the NSDictionary, not the JSON string.

Comment: Did you inspect the returned dictionary in the debugger? To me it seems like you get back an NSDictionary with a NSArray for the key "conferences". The NSArray in turn doesn't store key value pairs but other NSArrays with two elements each. Try accessing the first array with [stuff objectForKey:@"conferences"]; as an NSArray, then try to get the first object as a new NSArray and then the first and second element in that array should be the strings @"demo" and @"Demo Database". At least that is how it printed out NSDictionary makes it seem.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was exactly it. For some reason it did return a Dictionary with the key conferences which had all the data as an array.